# Can LaTeX be translated into HTML5?

Tags: math-mode, conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting LaTeX to HTML5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18139/converting-latex-to-html5)
>   [Convert LaTeX to HTML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html)

I would like to upload some notes on math on my site, and I thought it would look nicer to have it appear in a webpage manner rather than a list of hypertext that direct to pdfs. Is there some clever program that converts tex files into html that preserves the formulae without requiring something esoteric like mathml?

Comment: Tools such as [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) or [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsmath/) may be of use to you.

Comment: They are not plugins to convert LaTeX to HTML5.

Comment: I think you need to use a better title that reflects your question.

Comment: You might look at using R and knitr to generate HTML5. A starting point at this site, http://yihui.name/en/2012/05/how-to-make-html5-slides-with-knitr/